# How do I center a table?

Tags: css, center, css-tables

I was wondering how to center this table?   I'm having difficulties centering this. I've tried centering with CSS, but I may be doing something wrong when it comes to placing the tags in my CSS. I've tried the tags "table.tftable"

```
<style>
     table {
        -moz-border-radius: 5px !important;
         border-collapse: collapse !important;
         border: none !important;
     }
     table th, table td { border: none !important }
     table th:first-child {
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
     }
     table th:last-child {
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
     }
     table tr:last-child td:first-child {
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
             border-radius: 5px;
     }
     table tr:last-child td:last-child {
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
     }
     table tr:hover td { background-color: #2f2f2f !important }
    <table id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1">
       <style type="text/css">
     table.tftable {font-size:12px;color:#fbfbfb;width:100%;border-width: 1px;border-color: #686767;border-collapse: collapse;text-align:center;}
     table.tftable th {font-size:12px;background-color:#171515;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-color: #686767;text-align:center;}
     table.tftable tr {background-color:#000000;}
     table.tftable td {font-size:12px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-color: #686767;text-align:center;}
   </style>
      <table id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1" style="width: 680px;">
         bunch of content
      </table>
```

Comment: Do you mean centre the text in the table or center the whole table. Is the table in a parent container, if so post the HTML code for that and the CSS?

Comment: use margin:auto; like for any other block-level elements :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To centre the table on the page, or if it is inside a container put it in the centre of that use this code:

```
table.tftable {
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}
```

If the left and right margins are equal then compliant browsers should automatically assume that the element needs to be centre-aligned

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/uKyQu/

Comment: It helped and the the code is correct, but now the table seems to be carried to the right rather than the center of the body of my page.

Comment: @EstebanRodriguez Check if there is any other CSS code affecting your table, a quick way of fixing this would be to put my code at the bottom of the CSS as it is read last

Comment: And no other code seems to be affecting it. I've tried putting it last too and nothing has changed.

Comment: Hmm have you debugged with firebug?

Comment: No, I've never used FireBug. I just intalled the extension for Chrome, but I don't see anything as in errors or maybe I'm not doing what you're suggesting. If you want to see the website it's [here](http://estebanrodriguez.dx.am/pokemon/) Still under construction. It's for class so I just put whatever.

Comment: By the way, the code is a mess, I'm not very organized, but it seems like there is another code affecting it, probably the layout of the website itself. But I can't tell what it's trying to align with.

Comment: @EstebanRodriguez You should put the whole of the table element inside of the ColTwo div and set the width to `auto` or `100%` and then it will look okay.

Comment: @EstebanRodriguez P.S Firebug is a really really good tool to use to see how the page is laid out. Right click on a particular div or element on the page and select "Inspect With Firebug (Lite)" and inside of Firebug hover over that element in the code and it will highlight the space taken up by that element, as well as allowing you to edit the code on the right hand size inside of the browser. Completely changed the way I develop websites!

Comment: So I did as you said and also added div tags with colTwo ID and it's almost there, but it seems to be squeezing the letters and wanted space between the paragraphs and table. I just updated the site so you can see what I did.

Comment: Never mind that. The paragraphs are now out of place too. And setting the width as well as the whole table didn't work either.

Comment: To add space between the paragraph above and the table just do `table.tftable {margin-top:300px;}`

Comment: I went the other way again. And did as I did before just like you told me to include the table in colTwo and now it worked. That was a big what. Thanks a lot. It worked now.

Comment: @EstebanRodriguez I'm glad I could be of help. Just play around with the table's margins and im sure you will get it pixel perfect

Answer (score 0):

To center the table, You should add this line:

```
table.tftable { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
```